# Open different maps with different annotation

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm making an app with multiple annotations on a mapview.  I succeeded in displaying the annotations on the mapview.

I want to use the app to find different stores in one country. So I have all the coordinates and I want that when an annotation is clicked, the Maps app gets launched and the user can get a route from his current location.

My problem is that when I use the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` function, every annotation displays the information of the first coordinates I filled in.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self plotAnnotations];
}

-(void)plotAnnotations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
    coordinate1.latitude = 52.511917;
    coordinate1.longitude = 4.994776;
    MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate1 title:@"Basic-Fit Purmerend"];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2;
    coordinate2.latitude = 51.972618;
    coordinate2.longitude = 5.310799;
    MyLocation *annotation2 = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate2 title:@"Basic-Fit Aalsmeer"];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
    coordinate1.latitude = 52.511917;
    coordinate1.longitude = 4.994776;
    NSDictionary *addressDict1 = @{(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStreetKey:@"Grotenhuysweg 100, 1447 Purmerend, Nederland"};
    MKPlacemark *placeMark1 = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:coordinate1 addressDictionary:addressDict1];

    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark1];
    [mapItem setName:@"Basic-Fit Purmerend"];
    [mapItem setUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.basic-fit.nl/sportschool/Purmerend"]];



    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2;
    coordinate2.latitude = 51.972618;
    coordinate2.longitude = 5.310799;
    NSDictionary *addressDict2 = @{(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStreetKey:@"Molenvliet 18A, Aalsmeer, Nederland"};
    MKPlacemark *placeMark2 = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:coordinate2 addressDictionary:addressDict2];

    MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark2];
    [mapItem2 setName:@"Basic-Fit Aalsmeer"];
    [mapItem2 setUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.basic-fit.nl/sportschool/aalsmeer"]];


    NSArray *mapPoints = @[mapItem];
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapPoints launchOptions:nil];

    NSArray *mapPoints1 =@[mapItem2];
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapPoints1 launchOptions:nil];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

I eventually want to display more than 2 annotations on the map.  But when I select an annotation, the data provided by coordinate1 are displayed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work so far. The problem is in the -mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped: delegate method. This method is called when an annotation on the map view is tapped. You're trying to configure and open the Maps app for both of your example annotations in this delegate method which you shouldn't be doing. You should be opening the Maps app using the annotation view that you're given access to. The reason why the first annotation's details are being shown no matter what is because

```
NSArray *mapPoints = @[mapItem];
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapPoints launchOptions:nil];
```

will get called first any time you tap on an annotation.

Here's some stuff that I suggest you do.

You should modify your MyLocation class to have a NSDictionary property that will hold the address and a NSURL property to hold your URL.

So your -plotAnnotations method would look like this now:

```
-(void)plotAnnotations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
    coordinate1.latitude = 52.511917;
    coordinate1.longitude = 4.994776;
    MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate1 title:@"Basic-Fit Purmerend"];
    // Set the address for this annotation
    annotation.address = @{(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStreetKey:@"Grotenhuysweg 100, 1447 Purmerend, Nederland"};
    annotation.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.basic-fit.nl/sportschool/Purmerend"];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2;
    coordinate2.latitude = 51.972618;
    coordinate2.longitude = 5.310799;
    MyLocation *annotation2 = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate2 title:@"Basic-Fit Aalsmeer"];
    // Set the address for this annotation
    annotation2.address = @{(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStreetKey:@"Molenvliet 18A, Aalsmeer, Nederland"};
    annotation.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.basic-fit.nl/sportschool/aalsmeer"];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];
}
```

Now your -mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped: delegate method will look like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // You can retrieve your annotation using the annotation property of MKAnnotationView
    MyLocation *annotation = (MyLocation *)view.annotation;

    // Then you configure everything like you were doing
    MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:annotation.coordinate addressDictionary:annotation.address];

    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
    [mapItem setName:annotation.title];
    [mapItem setUrl:annotation.url];

    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mapItem] launchOptions:nil];
}
```

Something better to do would be to create a class called Place that has properties that stores all of your data pieces. Then you would modify your MyLocation class to initialize with your Place class. Then you would just access your Place class every time you have access to an annotation.

Comment: That worked? Great thank you, i finally got what i was looking for! I will try to understand and implement it the way you told me, then i will look into the second suggestion you made, thank you very much!